# Share stream with clusters in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

Is there's a way to share stream between master and clusters in node.js? I read about "sendHandle" can pass server object and sockets, but not sured if it can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `message-stream` or adapt that code to use `worker.send()`.  Or update `ipc-stream`.  They are in different processes so they can't actually share the same stream.

Comment: In other worlds, I will have to send all messages one by one from Master to every cluster in clusters.workers and create new stream from that messages at every cluster?

Comment: If you really need streams and really need to use cluster then I would adapt a module like those which yes it does create streams in each worker and in each worker (there is only one cluster).  If you want to broadcast a message from the master to all child workers, that's different than what you mentioned, but you would I think need to send to each worker if you're going that route.  Perhaps you want a regular message queue?  I think it might help to know more about how your application works and what you are using this for.